# Adding new tr with textboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to add a new row of textboxes.

The code won't work even if there is no error when I opened the developer tool.

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FNABg/1/) to view the sample of what I've made.

I'm using:

```
$(document.createElement('tr')).attr('id', 'textbox_holder_' + family_rel_counter);
```

Comment: tip: jQuery makes elements for you. Just use `$('<tr/>')`

Comment: @Asad - That should be `$('<tr>')`. Yours is just a selector.

Comment: @JosephSilber I know, I've already edited it to `$('<tr/>')`. Maybe you have to refresh the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is wrong

```
$('add_new_line_fam_rel')
```

should be

```
$('#add_new_line_fam_rel')
```

because it's an ID

http://jsfiddle.net/sEQXu/

Comment: good eyes.. lol.. sorry bout that... I always get this staff wrong.. XD

Comment: @KevinSteveManingo np :) glad to help